# Accessing csv file from blob container through Azure notebook

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I want to access a file that is around 2GB in size from the container in blob storage using Azure Python notebooks, but for some reason I am coming across this error.

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'part-00000-tid-9128541598398997257-8ae9f3ab-ad94-4ed6-ac2d-91b488393378-72-1-c000.csv'

[Here is the snippet of code that worked for me before, but for some reason is not working now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kshj.png)

Comment: Please post code and output as [text, not images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included the storage account url and it worked for me.
Here is the code for your reference

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd

STORAGEACCOUNTNAME= "<Storage account Name>"
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= "<Storage account key>"
LOCALFILENAME= "<Local file name>"
CONTAINERNAME= "<Container name>"
BLOBNAME= "<blob name>"
STORAGEACCOUNTURL="https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net"

#To download the blob
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME, snapshot=None)
with open(LOCALFILENAME, "wb") as my_blob:
    blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
    blob_data.readinto(my_blob)

#Read the blob
dataframe_blobdata = pd.read_csv(LOCALFILENAME)
print(dataframe_blobdata)
```

Here is the output

[image]

REFERENCES:
[Explore data in Azure Blob storage with pandas - Team Data Science Process - Azure Architecture Center | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-science-process/explore-data-blob)